# empty string changing to 0 for int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Very unique..... **and not authorized to change collation**

i have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE BT_INPUT_CHK
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RELID] [int] NULL,
    [OPNO] [varchar](35) NULL
)
```

and when i am inserting data

```
INSERT ZBT_INPUT_CHK ([ID],[RELID],[OPNO])
VALUES('1000002','','')
```

the problem starts here.
for varchar empty string inserted as same, **but for int empty string is changing to 0.**

collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS

can anyone please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Do you expect an integer to hold an empty string? Would you rather it result with an error?

Comment: @JonnyHenly: i am trying to make the column not null, and even if empty string pass, it should throw error. so it should not allow null or empty string to insert. but in my case the empty string is converting to 0, and inserting to table.

Comment: @GiladGreen: i am trying to make the column not null, and even if empty string pass, it should throw error. so it should not allow null or empty string to insert. but in my case the empty string is converting to 0, and inserting to table.

Comment: Well converting the empty string (`''`) to `0` is by design.

Comment: Why are you passing string values to integer columns? That doesn't make sense. (Other DBMS would rightfully reject the insert statement)

Comment: This exact case will have to be handled and rejected by the code that reads the file. Or you would first insert into a temp table with more text columns and validate that before you insert into the real table.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks Pal...

Answer (score 0):

When empty sting is implicitly converted to INT it converts to ZERO. if you need to set it to NULL then use NULLIF function.

```
DECLARE @RELID VARCHAR(10) = ''

INSERT ZBT_INPUT_CHK ([ID],[RELID],[OPNO])
VALUES('1000002',NULLIF(@RELID,''),'')
```

Comment: OP does not want to set it to NULL. *"I am trying to make the column not null"* - from OP's comments.

Comment: OP want to raise an error for NULL instead adding a row with ZERO when there is empty string.

Comment: @Jatin: Sorry, but value are inserting from flat file to table.

Answer (score 0):

[Check This](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/insert_empty_string_to_numeric_column)..You will get clear idea on Inserting Empty String to Numeric Column

```
INSERT into BT_INPUT_CHK ([ID],[RELID],[OPNO]) VALUES('1000007',NULL,'');
```

Comment: The values are coming from flat file, i don't want empty string to be inserted. so i have made the column not null, but empty string is getting inserted as 0. which is error value. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    CREATE TABLE #BT_INPUT_CHK
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RELID] [int] NULL,
    [OPNO] [varchar](35) NULL
)

INSERT #BT_INPUT_CHK ([ID],[RELID],[OPNO])
VALUES('1000002',(case when cast('' as varchar(10))='' then 'Error' else '' end),'')
```